# Does a PIC 16197 Microcontroller have D/A converter?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to send out values with analog pins which would be read by analog pins of any other microcontroller.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, the question whether your microcontroller has a certain peripheral is off-topic on StackOverflow, it is not a sufficiently specific question on programming. It would be on-topic in the specification for your hardware. Do you have access to that? As an aside, using a D/A-A/D chain for transmitting data seems a questionable concept to me. Wouldn't you prefer using communication peripherals, e.g.  the famous UART/RS232/serial? Or more advanced: IIC, CAN, ...

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the datasheet for a PIC 16197 microcontroller? Note that DAC is sometimes done with PWM features.

Comment: Did you mean PIC16F1619? What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're referring to the PIC16F1619, all the related information that you can look for your requirements is inside the datasheet, I invite you to look at [PIC16F1619 Web Page](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC16F1619) from Microchip and you will see all of the features and the current documentation to work with all of the peripherals included in this particular Microcontroller, however, according to the datasheet, the RA0 pin from this MCU has the feature to give an 8bit DAC output.

I hope this could help.